# Add a new attribute in serializer but doesn't appear

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add a new attribute apartment_sold in the Transaction serializer, but I seem it doesn't work!

serializes.py

```py
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    buyer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='buyer.username')
    apartment_sold = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='sold-detail', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = [
            'id','buyer','apartment_sold','timestamp'
        ]
```

views.py

```py
class SoldViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apartment.objects.filter(issold=True).order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ApartmentSerializer


class TransactionViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        transaction = serializer.save(buyer=self.request.user)
        transaction.apartment.issold = True
        transaction.apartment.save()
```

Comment: Can you add the content of the models.py here?

Comment: here https://pastebin.com/4dLmT8Pw. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think, in the model you defined the foreign key field name as `apartment`, not `apartment_sold`.

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    buyer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='buyer.username')
    apartment = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='sold-detail', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = [
            'id','buyer','apartment','timestamp'
        ]
```

Comment: i see that, `apartment` related with Apartment models, `apartment_issold` related with the view `SoldViewSet`. My purpose is to display apartments sold in transactions!

Comment: But each transaction has only one apartment, right?

Comment: ya! But because I use queryset to filter `issold=True` when a transaction is created, if I add `apartment` to  TransactionSerializer, the result will raise with error `"detail": "Not found."` when I click to detail apartment. So I want to instead of by `aparment_sold` and create a relationship to SoldViewSet. Sorry for bad English, and thank you help me !